# how to configure "stop the task if it runs longer than" for schtasks.exe

Tags: powershell, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I want to set the value for the option "Stop task if runs longer than" in the windows schedule task Trigger tab using Powershell.

Already tried with /DU switch but it is not working.

Below is the screenshot for the same.
[image: Windows Task Schedule Trigger Settings]

let me know in case of any further information is required.

@TobyU: I tried your suggestion as well but it is not setting up the required value. Below is the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it for **the whole task** at once:

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask"
$task.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT3H"
Set-ScheduledTask $task
```

Stops after 3 hours in the above example.

This is how you set it only for a **specific trigger**:

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask"
$task.Triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT3H"
Set-ScheduledTask $task
```

Where `Triggers[0]` is the specific trigger you want to adjust since `$task.Triggers` returns an array with all the available trigger objects for the specific task.

Comment: `ExecutionTimeLImit` string format: _The amount of time that is allowed to complete the task. The format for this string is PnYnMnDTnHnMnS, where nY is the number of years, nM is the number of months, nD is the number of days, 'T' is the date/time separator, nH is the number of hours, nM is the number of minutes, and nS is the number of seconds (for example, PT5M specifies 5 minutes and P1M4DT2H5M specifies one month, four days, two hours, and five minutes). A value of PT0S will enable the task to run indefinitely. When this parameter is set to Nothing, the execution time limit is infinite._

Comment: the string format here is not intuitive. At least not at first. you need to add information about how to make those strings in the desired format. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/tasksettings-executiontimelimit

Comment: The above provided PS script is not setting it up. but no luck, it is not changing the value.

Comment: It's setting it for the whole task, not only for a trigger.

Comment: @TobyU: you are right it is setting up for the whole task, but i want it only for a specific trigger. how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and PowerShell 7 and the following works well for me.

Creating a new task:

```
# Creating a task with multiple triggers and different execution limits
$taskName = "MyTask"

$trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At "2021-05-10 12:00:00"
$trigger1.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT20M"

$trigger2 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At "2021-05-13 17:30:30"
$trigger2.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT50M"

$taskTriggers = @(
    $trigger1,
    $trigger2
)

$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "notepad.exe"

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Trigger $taskTriggers -Action $taskAction
```

For updating the trigger of an existing task the solution proposed by @TobyU worked well for me:

```
# Updating execution limits of a task that already exists
$taskName = "MyTask"

$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName

$task.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT30S" # Global limit

$task.Triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT10S" # Limit for trigger 1
$task.Triggers[1].ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT15S" # Limit for trigger 2

Set-ScheduledTask $task
```

However, you can also completely replace the old trigger with a new one:

```
# Completely replacing all triggers with new one of an already existing task
$taskName = "MyTask"

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At "2021-05-17 17:17:17"
$trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT42M"

Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Trigger $trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create Schedule Task Remotely

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computername -Scriptblock 
{
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\app.exe” ' 
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 10am -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan - Minutes 480)     
    $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupID "BUILTIN\Administrators" - 
RunLevel Highest
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal - 
TaskName "Schedule_task_name" -Description "Task Description" 

    $Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Schedule_task_name"
    $Task.Triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit= "PT30M"
    Set-ScheduledTask $Task

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your format for the ExecutionTimeLimit may need tweaking. In my case, I wanted the setting removed (ie the tickbox unticked). I couldn't figure this out, but using the following format for ExecutionTimeLimit did work, so I could set it to a far away value: d.hh:mm:ss, ie 1000 days:

```
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit 1000.00:00:00
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'name' -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings
```

Comment: My memory may be rusty, and the implementation details may have changed since I worked on the Task Scheduler, but I recall the maximum execution time limit being 72 hours.